# What is the efficient way to check if an item is present in an array with up to 1000000 items ore more

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, processing-efficiency

If you want to check if an int value is present in an int[] array with up to 1000000 items what is the most efficient way to do this and minimize CPU cycles?

```
int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4};
value = 4
```

I know of using a for loop or something like this:

```
values.Contains(value);
Array.Exists(values , i => i==value );
Array.IndexOf(values, value) != -1;
```

Comment: Is the array sorted?

Comment: Yes it is sorted ascending

Comment: Then use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you have 1M items? Why array?

Comment: I got this question on a test and was wondering why I did't get full points for my answer.

Comment: What approach would you take for a unsorted array?

Comment: If you want to know why you didn't get full points, you should ask the person who graded the exam.

Comment: If I do a binarysearch (Array.BinarySearch(values, value)) on the value 4 I get result of 3. When I do a binarysearch on 7 I get  -3 why is that?

Comment: If your read the documentation you will see if you do `var index = ~result` (the `~` operator is the bitwise NOT operator), it will give you the index of the next value that is larger than the value you are looking for, if it larger than all values it will give you the index of the largest value + 1.

Comment: You wish to find out if Danny H is listed in the phone book. Do you start reading it from the first page and keep going until you find your name? The method that minimizes computer CPU cycles is probably very similar to the method that you would use to minimize brain cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your array is sorted the best way is to use the [`BinarySearch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
bool IsInArray(int[] values, int value)
{
    var index = Array.BinarySearch(values, value);
    return (index >= 0);
}
```

If the array is not sorted then the other 3 options you listed are all likely going to perform about exactly the same, I would just use `values.Contains(value);` as that is the simplest choice.

Comment: In fact this has an O(log n) performance (with a logarithm of base 2). For one million entries, at most 20 iterations are required. 2^20 ~ 1e6

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm:

1. If range is less than 10 elements, iterate till element is found.
2. Otherwise find middle element of your array and compare it to your value.
3. Depending on comparison result select new range (first or second half) and recursively run step 1.